# How to have even spacing in tableview cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have cells that resize automatically, and my problem becomes that I can't seem to have an even distance between the cells when the content in said cells differs.

Is there a way to go about fixing this? Maybe setting something to Aspect fit or fill?

[image]

Comment: my suggestion would be to include the spacing in the cells (make the cell background clear and insert a subview with a white background for the main cell content which is less high) or just use section headers for the spacing.

Comment: Are you referring to the height of the pale blue space behind the cells? It's a little hard to tell from your clip.

Comment: @MikeTaverne I am. That space is actually a part of the cell background. My problem it seems like is that it stretches itself out which I understand, but I read there were ways to keep certain parts of an image from distorting.

Comment: Are you subclassing the cell from UITableViewCell?

Comment: My recommendation is to expand your cell height in **.XIB** and add an empty UIView for cell spacing, that way you also can set what ever height, color, pattern you want from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

if you using Subclass of `UITableViewCell` with **.xib** the best way to do this is to increase your overall cell hight and add a `UIView` as subview just for spacing to the bottom.

This way you have access to that UIView and can change height, colors and even a pattern.

**Example:**

[image]